# Accents automatically replaced by digits after a POST query

Tags: php, encoding, http-post, bitbucket

I have a problem with the POST query made by Bitbucket to a personal page whenever a commit is made: the accentuated characters are replaced by digits.

Here is the message I use for the commit: `Démo test éà`

And here is what my page gets: `Du00e9mo test u00e9u00e0`

- I tried using `uft8_decode`, `utf8_encode`, `iconv` (with UTF-8 and
  ISO-8859-1) and others (based on posts I found)
- I saved my script in UTF-8
- I tried using `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: Have you tried url encoding?

Comment: Related: [PHP stripslashes() breaking emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52239971/2943403) and [Json from mysql breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46468014/2943403) and [JSON saved with file_put_contents() is having its end undesirably cut off](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27205648/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what would happen if you removed the backslashes \ from a JSON encoded string. The UTF encoding is correct (è is correctly 00e9).

If you use `stripslashes` in your code, do not, or use it (but it shouldn't be necessary) with a mapping function *after* `json_decode`.

This is what a rogue `stripslashes` would do:

```
<?php print json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode("Démo test éà"))) . "\n"; ?>

Du00e9mo test u00e9u00e0
```

If you have no control on the interface, you can try running the process in reverse to get back the correct string. This is a bit of a monstrous hack and is not really very robust, so I'd use it only as a **very last resort**:

```
<?php

$string = "Du00e9mo test u00e9u00e0";

$correct = preg_replace("/u([0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f])/", '\\u\\1', json_encode($string));

$string = json_decode($correct);

print "Output: $string\n";

?>

Output: Démo test éà
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I feel bad to not have noticed that! I was wondering why there was a `n` at the end and not a `\n`...

Comment: Heh. How did you think I guessed? *I* did it too :-) (and not only once :-( )