# JSON saved with file_put_contents() is having its end undesirably cut off

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to save a lot of json data into a file named test.json. I'm using PHP:

```
$json = stripslashes($_POST['json']);
file_put_contents("test.json",$json);
```

The data is saved in one line but for some reason the data is not saved completely. I'm not sure if it's a limitation of file_put_contents or $_POST. The limit seems to be 15,673 characters.

Comment: Have you tried echoing $json to see if it contains what you think it should?

Comment: The title is pretty much misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The string I was sending had ampersands and I had to do a uri encode then decode it on the PHP end.

JavaScript:

```
var obj = {firstName:"John & Johnson", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
var objStr = JSON.stringify(objStr);
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "write.php",
  data: 'json='+encodeURIComponent(objStr),
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  $json = urldecode($_POST['json']);
  $json = stripslashes($json);
  file_put_contents("test.json",$json);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

$_POST size depends upon the php configuration directive POST_MAX_SIZE which is usually set to 8 MB.

It could be possible that your request of file_put_contents not able to process completely within this execution time which is causing this issue.

Or probably you are running out of memory.

Try increase the memory limit and max_execution_time.

Comment: I used set_ini() to set max_execution_time to 0 and memory_limit to 1000M. POST_MAX_SIZE to 1000M. No change.