# Json from mysql breaks

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, unicode

i have some issue with a json stored in mysql TEXT field, the thing is that everything is OK until i use ' (single quote) the json then is saved \' and every time i save it back it appends a slash like: \' \\' \\' etc.

then some characters are not encoded correctly \u00e0

```
<div class="wpbs-calendar-legend" data-info="{&quot;default&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:{&quot;default&quot;:&quot;Available&quot;,&quot;hr&quot;:&quot;Slobodno&quot;,&quot;cs&quot;:&quot;Volno&quot;,&quot;da&quot;:&quot;Ledigt&quot;,&quot;nl&quot;:&quot;Vrij&quot;,&quot;en&quot;:&quot;Available&quot;,&quot;fr&quot;:&quot;Libre&quot;,&quot;de&quot;:&quot;Frei&quot;,&quot;hu&quot;:&quot;Szabad&quot;,&quot;it&quot;:&quot;Libero&quot;,&quot;ro&quot;:&quot;Disponobil&quot;,&quot;ru&quot;:&quot;\u0414\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0443\u043f\u043d\u043e&quot;,&quot;sk&quot;:&quot;Vo\u013en\u00fd&quot;,&quot;es&quot;:&quot;Libre&quot;,&quot;sv&quot;:&quot;Ledigt&quot;,&quot;uk&quot;:&quot;B\u0456\u043b\u044c\u043d\u043e&quot;,&quot;no&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#f1ffcc&quot;,&quot;splitColor&quot;:false,&quot;bookable&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;auto-pending&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;sync&quot;:&quot;no&quot;},&quot;1&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:{&quot;default&quot;:&quot;Booked&quot;,&quot;hr&quot;:&quot;Zauzeto&quot;,&quot;cs&quot;:&quot;Obsazeno&quot;,&quot;da&quot;:&quot;Booket&quot;,&quot;nl&quot;:&quot;Bezet&quot;,&quot;en&quot;:&quot;Booked&quot;,&quot;fr&quot;:&quot;Occup\u00e9&quot;,&quot;de&quot;:&quot;Belegt&quot;,&quot;hu&quot;:&quot;Foglalt&quot;,&quot;it&quot;:&quot;Prenotato&quot;,&quot;ro&quot;:&quot;Rezervat&quot;,&quot;ru&quot;:&quot;\u0417\u0430\u043d\u044f\u0442\u043e&quot;,&quot;sk&quot;:&quot;Obsaden\u00fd&quot;,&quot;es&quot;:&quot;Reservado&quot;,&quot;sv&quot;:&quot;Bokat&quot;,&quot;uk&quot;:&quot;\u0417\u0430\u0439\u043d\u044f\u0442\u043e&quot;,&quot;no&quot;:&quot;&quot;},&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#ff524c&quot;,&quot;splitColor&quot;:false,&quot;bookable&quot;:false,&quot;auto-pending&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;sync&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;},&quot;2&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:{&quot;en&quot;:&quot;>14H&quot;,&quot;nl&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;et&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;fi&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;fr&quot;:&quot;D\u00e8s 14H&quot;,&quot;de&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;pt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;ro&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;default&quot;:&quot;D\u00e8s 14H&quot;},&quot;color&quot;:&quot;#f1ffcc&quot;,&quot;splitColor&quot;:&quot;#ff524c&quot;,&quot;bookable&quot;:&quot;yes&quot;,&quot;hide&quot;:false,&quot;auto-pending&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;sync&quot;:&quot;no&quot;},&quot;3&quot;:{&quot;name&quot;:{&quot;en&quot;:&quot;<12H&quot;,&quot;nl&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;et&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;fi&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;fr&quot;:&quot;Jusqu\\" \u00e0="" 10h","de":"","pt":"","ro":"","default":"jusqu\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\'\u00e0="" 10h"},"color":"#ff524c","splitcolor":"#f1ffcc","bookable":"yes","hide":false,"auto-pending":"no","sync":"no"}}'=""></div>
```

and in my insepct window looks like this:

[image: developer console]

I am using WordPress so this json_encoded string is saved using update_option into the database. I've tried to stripslashes() the json encoded string on update_option but that did not solve the issue.

may somebody can help me out here?

Thanks for your time on this!

Comment: The data info is htmlentity coded.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your SQL insert is escaping - very correctly - the data.

Now when you need to get the data from SQL you need to remove escaping by the use of stripslashes.

So if your variable is `$jsonResult` use it as `stripslashes($jsonResult)`.

Comment: i've already tried stripslashes and does not solve my issue as the json_encoded string is save using WordPress's update_option function (need to edit question to reflect that i use wordpress)

Comment: Escaping doesn't work like that. The slashes are added, the result it sent to the database, the slashes are consumed by the SQL parser and not included in the data stored in the database.

Answer (score 1):

No, not htmlentities, not stripslashes.  If you got the JSON from `json_encode()`, use an extra parameter to avoid the "Unicode" encoding:

```
$x = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

See Example #2 in 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
(Requires PHP 5.4.0)