# PHP stripslashes() breaking emojis

Tags: php, json, encoding

Emojis are breaking after I `json_encode` and `stripslashes` my array.

`$msg = "Yeah Emojis are cool! ";`

If I echo `$msg` it will display as expected. With the emojis rendered.

But after the code below...

```php
$postarray = array("name" => "Adam", "message" => $msg);

echo stripslashes(json_encode($postarray));
```

`$postarray` returns a valid JSON but my emojis are displayed like so

`ud83dudcb0ud83dudcb0ud83dudcb5`

Any solutions?

Comment: Stripslashes breaks the JSON encoding. Also a bit more context please, before asking for solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stripslashes()` is breaking your data.

Valid JSON should not contain exotic Unicode symbols (which Emojis are) so `json_encode()` turns them into escaped character codes. `""` becomes `"\ud83d\udcb0"` and `"`" becomes `"\ud83d\udcb5"`.

Stripslashes removes the backslash that indicates you're dealing with Unicode characters so there's no way for the receiving application to know that those character codes need to be turned back into Emojis.

You should never call `stripslashes()` on a JSON string. The risk of invalidating your JSON is too great. For example, if your data contains a string with a literal `"` character, it will be escaped as `\"` and stripping that `\` off will invalidate your JSON:

```
$data = ['value' => 'My "awesome" value'];
$json = json_encode($data);
// {"value":"My \"awesome\" value"}

$stripped = stripslashes($json);
// {"value":"My "awesome" value"}
//               ^ Syntax error right here
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the option 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE' to json_encode.

```
$msg = "Yeah Emojis are cool! ";
echo $msg;

$postarray = array("name" => "Adam", "message" => $msg);
echo stripslashes(json_encode($postarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```